# Changing from spi bus to i2c bus to transfer register data of wm5102 in raspberry pi with wolfson audio card

Tags: linux, i2c, wolfson-audio-card

I'm using wolfson audio card on raspberry pi b+ board.Current wm5102 driver uses spi bus to transfer register data but i want to use i2c bus to transfer data.By reading data sheet of 5102 i understood that we can use i2c bus also to transfer data.So what i did is i blacklisted all codecs that uses i2c buses and i added few lines in board file to work 5102 with i2c bus.here is my code.

```
{
 I2C_BOARD_INFO("wm5102", 0x1b),
.platform_data = &snd_rpi_wsp_spi_platform_data,
},
```

actually this is what we have to do all regulators are loading correctly but i am getting error logs while booting i.e., "Failed to read ID register: -5".

What is my doubt is whether i2c connected properly to wm5102? or anything i am missing ? do i need to add anything ?

Thanks